# I can't install VCRemote on MacOS 10.13.6

Tags: macos, cordova, npm, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to install VCRemote on MacOS but when I try

> npm install -g --unsafe-perm vcremote

I get the following errors

```
ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:262:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:189:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:248:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 17.7.0
gypgyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "build" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/vcremote/node_modules/node-ios-device/binding/node-v64-darwin-x64/node_ios_device.node" "--module_name=node_ios_device" "--module_path=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/vcremote/node_modules/node-ios-device/binding/node-v64-darwin-x64"
gyp ERR! cwd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/vcremote/node_modules/node-ios-device
gyp ERR! node -v v10.15.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
 ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:262:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:189:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:248:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 17.7.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "build" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/vcremote/node_modules/node-ios-device/binding/node-v64-darwin-x64/node_ios_device.node" "--module_name=node_ios_device" "--module_path=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/vcremote/node_modules/node-ios-device/binding/node-v64-darwin-x64"
gyp ERR! cwd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/vcremote/node_modules/node-ios-device
gyp ERR! node -v v10.15.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --module=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/vcremote/node_modules/node-ios-device/binding/node-v64-darwin-x64/node_ios_device.node --module_name=node_ios_device --module_path=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/vcremote/node_modules/node-ios-device/binding/node-v64-darwin-x64' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/vcremote/node_modules/node-ios-device/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:189:13)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:970:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Darwin 17.7.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/vcremote/node_modules/node-ios-device/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/vcremote/node_modules/node-ios-device
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v10.15.1
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.6.31
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok 
Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --module=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/vcremote/node_modules/node-ios-device/binding/node-v64-darwin-x64/node_ios_device.node --module_name=node_ios_device --module_path=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/vcremote/node_modules/node-ios-device/binding/node-v64-darwin-x64' (1)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-ios-device@1.1.0 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the node-ios-device@1.1.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Am I missing something? I'm fairly new to NPM, I'm following this guide from Microsoft [guide here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/cross-platform/install-and-configure-tools-to-build-using-ios?view=vs-2017) to set up vcremote
I can attach the full error log if needed as well.
Any guidance or help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to execute the command as a root?

Comment: yes I have tried executing as root.

Comment: Have you found a solution for this?

Comment: No, unfortunately, I never did.